# Is there a way to contribute defaults for `tokenColors` within a language extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I work on a new grammar for a language and I introduce new scopes.

I want to define sane default colors for these new scopes like it could be done with the [color-contribution](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.colors)

The following example shows how it's done for `colors`:

```
{
  "contributes": {
    "colors": [
      {
        "id": "superstatus.error",
        "description": "Color for error message in the status bar.",
        "defaults": {
          "dark": "errorForeground",
          "light": "errorForeground",
          "highContrast": "#010203"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to set defaults for `tokenColors` within my extension like:

```
{
  "contributes": {
    "tokenColors": [
      {
        "scopes": ["my.warning.new.scope.waring", "my.warining.other.new.scope"],
        "description": "Color for warning message in unknown .",
        "defaults": {
          "dark": "wariningForeground",
          "light": "wariningForeground",
          "highContrast": "#010203"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I don't want to create a new theme that inherits from another theme, bc the user have to select that explicitly.

I want do define sane defaults for a scope, bc most themes won't define a color for my new scope.

Is there a way to define default token colors for token scopes without creating a new theme?